# Twisted: let one Factory fire event for the other on data update

Tags: python, twisted

I have seen this answer [Sending data received in one Twisted factory to second factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737885/sending-data-received-in-one-twisted-factory-to-second-factory) , but my problem is somewhat different.

I have two servers each listening on their own ports for incoming connections. Server 1 (XMLFactory) receives request from a client, saves current state into MemCache key and sends HTTP request to external server.

```
reactor.listenTCP(int(appPort), XMLFactory(), interface=XMLhost)
reactor.listenTCP(int(uptPort), UPTFactory(), interface=UPThost)
```

External server returns a reply to a Server 2 (UPTFactory). Server 2 updates MemCache key.

The issue is to let Server 1's respective client connection know that key was updated, so it can update its client.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is just an issue of communication between the two factories, like the link you posted. The `UPTFactory` has to call a `XMLFactory` method that will notify all interested clients (which are already kept in a list)

Comment: Thank you! I figured out that myself last night, by just keeping a list of clients (Protocols) in an array and then executing send-to-client procedure call of Server 1 from a Server 2 factory.