# sending data to multiple factories receieved from a different factory

Tags: python, twisted

there is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737885/sending-data-received-in-one-twisted-factory-to-second-factory), but no clear answers.

I need to be able to listen on one port (9000), and send to other servers on different ports (7777,8888,9999).

The code I wrote *does* work, but I'm not sure if it is the best method.  It looks non-pythonic to continually use `self.factory.factoryObjectList`.  I wish I could assign this to another value to clean up the code a little.

Is my method overkill?  Can this be done in an easier way?

```
import sys
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ClientFactory, ServerFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.python import log

class RX_Protocol(LineReceiver):

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.sendMessageToConnections(self.factory.factoryObjectList, data)
        self.transport.write('sent \'%s\' to %d servers\n' % (data.strip(), self.countConnections(self.factory.factoryObjectList)))

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write('hello telnet user! Let\'s send a message to all connections\n')

    def sendMessageToConnections(self, factoryObjectList, data):
        for factoryObject in factoryObjectList:  # iterate through list of factory objects, 1 for each server
            for connection in factoryObject.factory.connections:  # now iterate through the actual connections of each factory
                connection.transport.write(data)

    def countConnections(self, factoryObjectList):
        counter = 0
        for factoryObject in factoryObjectList:
            if factoryObject.state == 'connected':
                counter += 1
        return counter


class RX_Factory(ServerFactory):
    protocol = RX_Protocol

    def __init__(self, factoryObjectList):
        self.factoryObjectList = factoryObjectList


## TX Stuff ##
class TX_Protocol(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.connections.append(self)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.connections.remove(self)


class TX_Factory(ClientFactory):  # subclass your factory of choice (Factory, ClientFactory, ServerFactory)
    protocol = TX_Protocol

    def __init__(self):
        self.connections = []

# spawn these in new terminals using nc -l XXXX
servers = [('localhost', 7777),
           ('localhost', 8888),
           ('localhost', 9999)]
# servers = [('localhost', 7777)]  # easier than opening 3 terminals

factoryObjectList = []  # will hold the multiple factories we use to connect to servers

# give us better STDOUT twisted logging
log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

for host, port in servers:
    factoryObjectList.append(reactor.connectTCP(host, port, TX_Factory()))

reactor.listenTCP(9000, RX_Factory(factoryObjectList))  #RX_Factory now "knows" about connections to servers
reactor.run()
```

Comment: "non-pythonic", "overkill", "clean up" are all vague, subjective ways to describe a problem.  Describe what you think is actually *wrong* with the code or you're not very likely to get answers that tell you how to do something right.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about working code - it should probably be migrated to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Should have been clearer. Very new to async code and twisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method looks typical to me.

Take a look at SO: [What is the correct way to access a protocols transport in Twisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329856/what-is-the-correct-way-to-access-a-protocols-transport-in-twisted) (which also links to another SO: [Persistent connection in Twisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265609/persistent-connection-in-twisted)) there is a note about the newer "endpoint" system, you might like its style better.